# Storm - Supervisors crashing on reboot

Tags: apache-storm

This is an issue that is simply driving me nuts. I have a one machine Storm instance running on my Local LAN. I am currently running `v0.9.1-incubating` release version (from [the Apache Incubator site](http://www.carfab.com/apachesoftware/incubator/storm/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating.tar.gz). The issue is simply that my `storm supervisor` process **refuses to start** after **EVERY SINGLE** reboot. The hack fix is quite simple, remove the `supervisor` and `workers` folders from the storm local directory and re run the process; things run hunky dory then on until next reboot.

I'm providing every bit of information I think might be relevant to debug this issue. Please ask for more if needed, but just help me get some resolution.

PS: It doesn't matter if I have topologies running or not.

1. Zookeeper version: 3.4.5
2. Storm version: 0.9.1-incubating (uses Netty transport)
3. Both Storm and Zookeeper run on the same machine.
4. supervisord version: 3.0b2
5. OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
6. Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor × 6
7. RAM: 5.6 GiB

**Supervisor config**

```
[program:zookeeper]
command=/path/to/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh "start-foreground"
process_name=zookeeper
directory=/path/to/zookeeper/bin
stdout_logfile=/var/log/zookeeper.log        ; stdout log path, NONE$
stderr_logfile=/var/log/err.zookeeper.log        ; stderr log path, $
priority=2
user=root


[program:storm-nimbus]
command=/path/to/storm/bin/storm nimbus
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=2
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/storm/nimbus.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/storm/nimbus.out.log
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=2
priority=10


[program:storm-ui]
command=/path/to/storm/bin/storm ui
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=2
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/storm/ui.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/storm/ui.out.log
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=2
priority=500


[program:storm-supervisor]
command=/path/to/storm/bin/storm supervisor
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=2
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/storm/supervisor.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/storm/supervisor.log.log
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=2
priority=600


[program:storm-logviewer]
command=/path/to/storm/bin/storm logviewer
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=2
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/storm/log.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/storm/log.out.log
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=2
priority=900
```

**Storm config**

```
#Zookeeper
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "192.168.1.11"

# Nimbus
nimbus.host: "192.168.1.11"
nimbus.childopts: '-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dprocess=storm'

# UI
ui.port: 9090
ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dprocess=storm"

# Supervisor
supervisor.childopts: '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dprocess=storm'


# Worker
worker.childopts: '-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dprocess=storm'

storm.local.dir: "/path/to/storm"

storm.messaging.transport: "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context"
storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads: 1
storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads: 1
storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 5242880
storm.messaging.netty.max_retries: 100
storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms: 1000
storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms: 100
```

**Error message**
[Pastebin for log error message](http://pastebin.com/Z7v4QLiU). I'm cross posting the relevant bits here.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:86) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.snapshot(LocalState.java:45) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.get(LocalState.java:56) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes.invoke(supervisor.clj:207) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__4070.doInvoke(core.clj:2343) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2593.invoke(event.clj:39) ~[na:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2322) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2791) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2014-03-11 12:27:25 b.s.util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
```

Comment: Can you fallback to the latest stable release and see whats happen?

Comment: @Chiron This is the latest stable release (according to https://storm.incubator.apache.org/downloads.html). Hoping to migrate this issue I've tried versions 0.9.0 and 0.9.0.1 and 0.9.0-rc1. The same thing happens.

Comment: @Chiron I've already mentioned that what you recommended is what I have to do repeatedly on every reboot. I'm trying to not have to do that every time

Comment: There is this an open bug STORM-113 regarding deserialization and thread safety.  I wonder if this problem could be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-113 if so you may be able to change the serializer and deserializer to thread local vars per the reporters comments.  You would need to rebuild from the source.

Comment: I've experienced this bug too when I updated my storm version from 0.9.0.1 to 0.9.1 on the same machine. After I deleted the `supervisor` and `worker` dirs under `storm.local.dir` which specified in conf, it started normally.

Comment: @halfelf you comment should be an accepted answer. We have storm on vagrant boxes and I saw exact same behaviour when vagrant box is abruptly suspended. Deleting supervisor and workers dir definitely works

Comment: @Liutauras, that much is part of the question itself. I was really asking for a way to not have to do that every time.

Comment: same thing happens to my storm supervisor host: 1) crash and restart, 2) deserilazie / NPE error. And as many mentioned, the only way I found to make it back on live is remove STORM_DATA/supervisor dir. I also post this question on storm user email list and got no response yet...

Answer (score 5):

We had that exact same problem (supervisor crashing on start and same log error message) when we had a power outage on 2 of our development servers. I guess just stopping the server without previously stopping the supervisor would have the same effect.

The only working solution we found was to **remove the "*storm-local/supervisor*" folder** (I guess something in there got corrupted).

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this similar issue. I used to remove the local folder always and restart the topology.