# Error while starting Supervisor (STORM)

Tags: apache-storm

I get an error that says " Error while processing an event" whenever I start the supervisor(of storm).. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Please post the full error stack. Is it an EOFException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicated of [Storm - Supervisors crashing on reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318783/storm-supervisors-crashing-on-reboot/26124740#26124740)

Just remove the "storm-local/supervisor" folder and it should go.